# Animation stops when ListBoxItem not visible (WPF)

Tags: wpf, animation, listboxitem

I have animation on list box items.  When the list box item is not visible, ie. scrolled past visible in the listbox the animation seems to stop.  When it is scrolled back into view it appears to start where it left off.
Does anyone now how to keep the animation running?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turn off Virtualization on the listbox - the item is getting destroyed when it's not in view.

Comment: Seconded. Through techniques like virtualization, WPF conserves CPU & RAM resources by discarding or recycling objects which cannot affect the on-screen rendering. ... like listbox items that are scrolled out of view.

Perhaps you'd consider detecting when a listbox item is scrolled out of view, and either terminate the animation, or set it to it's end-state?

As Paul correctly states, the easy (and resource unfriendly) way to solve your problem is simply to turn off virtualization.